# Why is my passion fruit's leaves are yellow? Is it dying?

Tags: fruit-trees, indoors, diseases

I've bought a plant of passion fruit.

Recently I've changed the ground of it.
Several days ago the leaves began to be yellow and curled up.
The photos are below.

Could you please give an advise how to reanimate it?
Thanks in advance

[image]
[image]

Comment: Which soil did you use? To me it seems a "nutrient"/fertilizer problem. Wrong soil could be the cause (wrong pH will prevent root to capture many useful molecules). Leave fertilizers could help temporarily, but we need more information about soil (and why did you changed it), and if you fertilize it (and how/how much)